# XHTML & CKEditor question

Tags: xhtml, ckeditor

Does CKEditor output data xhtml compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

Try running the output through something like HTMLPurifier.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Added bonus of clean content, especially if user generated.

Comment: @mac, yes just process the data (on save) from CKEditor through HTMLPurifier. Out of the box HTMLPurifier will perform removals and transforms to give your 100% compliant XHTML.

Comment: do I need to configure HTMLPurifier to output 100% compliant XHTML?

Comment: @mac Out of the box it will return 100% compliant XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is itself not XHTML compliant, and can not be served on an XHTML page (with the XHTML mime type `application/xhtml+xml`)

- https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/2807
- https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/4576
- https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7849